# Why POM.xml default template has an error? cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

today I had fight with theoretically simple Maven. I did everything like in tutorial, but I had an issue:
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'.
[Link to see template error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIrgX.png)

I had no idea why is it not working so I tried to do it way around. I created normal java project,
then converted it into Maven project and thanks to this I received pom.xml file which works.

I wanna share it with you and maybe somebody will take some conclusions. I am totally new in java and I have error for the second time which does not come, because of my mistake - I hope.

Here you can see notpad comparation: [difference in declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqWyP.png)

Not working declaration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

And here corrected one by adding "s" to "http":

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

That "s" can be added to any "http" to exists at least once.

Comment: It works fine with http here, possibly an issue with your network setup.

Comment: `http` is being redirected to `https`. It depends on the tool if it can handle such redirects.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your issue in the current Eclipse 2021-12 with m2e 1.19.0.20211116-0804: in the preferences _XML > XML Catalog_ there is `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd` as a plug-in specified entry for me. Is your Eclipse up to date and do you have this entry in the preferences?

Comment: @RobertScholte There should be an XML catalog entry for that not requiring to following the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Issue:POM.xml default template has an error? cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'

Solution :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I also observed this error. However, I got it resolved in a different way.
I did not add any s to the fist line. It was already there as part of the default pom.xml

Error Observed: cvc-elt.1.1: Cannot find the declaration element project.
Solution :Upon right clicking on the "https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" and selecting the option " force download the resources", the error was gone.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? There is no option to download on Eclipse 4.21 / STS 4

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and when i scroll to right its showing error on end of that project line, when i hover over it and selected force download resources its fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).